# adding "enum-like" type to propTypes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I would like to add a type defined as follows to propTypes:

```js
export type AlarmSeverity =
  | 'inactive'
  | 'nominal'
  | 'caution'

const AlarmLed : FunctionComponent<AlarmLedProps>(severity): React.ReactElement => {...}

export interface AlarmLedProps {
   readonly severity: AlarmSeverity;
}

AlarmLed.PropTypes= {
   severity: oneOf([
     'inactive',
     'nominal',
     'caution',
   ]),
}
```

This setting gives me an error:

```
Types of property 'severity' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AlarmSeverity'
```

Do you have an idea how I can achieve that or something similar?

Comment: Any specific reason you are using TS with propTypes?

Comment: To have type verification both at compile and runtime. the data we'll be using might be corrupted.

Comment: Why not just use an `enum`? Looks like you're already using TS, so just leverage their type.

Comment: To be clear, when you say runtime, do you mean during development or production?

Comment: as others stated why are you setting up TS and propTypes? Also change AlarmLed.PropTypes to "AlarmLed.propTypes" Edit: based on docs looks like propTypes is checked only in dev mode. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: runtime mostly during dev, it will help make everything more robest, but it might be useful in prod...We don't really know yet. Going with enum is an option, but it would require quite a lot of re-write on many already-written pieces, so I would prefer if I had another option.

Comment: There is a a [babel-plugin](https://github.com/milesj/babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes) that automatically generates propTypes from your type definitions. You might want to check it out. Not really answering the question, but might help.